# Change footer height while having sticky footer (Materialize CSS)

Tags: html, css, materialize

Is it possible, when using the materialize framework, to have a smaller footer height (40-50px) while having it as a sticky footer. Whenever I try it there is whitespace below the footer. Below the html and css I used:

```css
 footer {
        background-color: #00bcd4;
        height: 40px;
    }
```

```html
  <footer class="white-text">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col 16 s12">
                    <h5 class="white-text">Lorem ipsum</h5>
                    <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">Lorem ipsum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

Comment: where is your sample code

Comment: Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: As footer is at the end of the page, what do you mean by sticky? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_position_sticky here you can see what sticky is.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the answer you are looking for

layout.css:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

/*


*/
```

The html page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <p>Your website content here.</p>
            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <p>Copyright (c) 2008</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The solution is not using Materialize library.

Comment: Dude, it doesn't matter wether you are using boot strap or materialise. This is just a simple example of how to do it. This solution works with materialise as well as i am also using materialize.

Comment: Sorry "dude" it does not work for me - it makes the footer push up from the bottom of the page. Also setting a sticky footer with set pixels is just bad practice.

Comment: Well, maybe because i implemented this in .net ! it was working fine for me Dude !